# Install Samples, Binaries and Docker Images for 1.4.2 version failes - with baseos and javaenc fabric image (Bug in bootstrap.sh script?)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I followed the official fabric "release-1.4" instructions and got problems with the download install script:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 1.4.2 1.4.2 0.4.15`

**cannot pull nodeenv and baseos** cause of "not found" error.

**Output:**

```
==> FABRIC IMAGE: baseos

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-baseos:1.4.2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-baseos:1.4.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: nodeenv

Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:1.4.2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:1.4.2
```

Installed after the LTS Installation file 1.4.2 (missing: baseos, nodeenv):

```
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     1.4.2               1cd707531ce7        4 weeks ago         1.76GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     latest              1cd707531ce7        4 weeks ago         1.76GB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          1.4.2               f289675c9874        4 weeks ago         253MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          latest              f289675c9874        4 weeks ago         253MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       1.4.2               0abc124a9400        4 weeks ago         1.55GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       latest              0abc124a9400        4 weeks ago         1.55GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       1.4.2               fc0f502399a6        4 weeks ago         1.43GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       latest              fc0f502399a6        4 weeks ago         1.43GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     1.4.2               362021998003        4 weeks ago         173MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     latest              362021998003        4 weeks ago         173MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        1.4.2               d79f2f4f3257        4 weeks ago         178MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        latest              d79f2f4f3257        4 weeks ago         178MB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   0.4.15              20c6045930c8        5 months ago        1.43GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   latest              20c6045930c8        5 months ago        1.43GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       0.4.15              b4ab82bbaf2f        5 months ago        1.44GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       latest              b4ab82bbaf2f        5 months ago        1.44GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     0.4.15              8de128a55539        5 months ago        1.5GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     latest              8de128a55539        5 months ago        1.5GB
```

For me there seems to be a bug in the bootstrap.sh script that pulls all dockers images (compare official guide here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html):
The relevant extract part of the file bootstrap.sh that is linked behind the bit.ly URL:

```
dockerFabricPull() {
local FABRIC_TAG=$1
for IMAGES in peer orderer ccenv tools baseos nodeenv javaenv; do
...
```

For "baseos" and "nodeenv" there exists no 1.4.2 version in docker-hub to pull. This is why this error occures.
They exists only for Version 2.0 (Master Release) or 0.4.15.
For nodeenv there exists only a 2.0 file.

1. This bug should be fixed
2. Which version should I take to receive the full 1.4.2 version features?
3. What is the main purpose of the docker images: nodeenv and baseos. I couldn't find them in the documentation.

Thank you! Also - if you help me with some parts here.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked with our release manager. This is a side effect of the fact that we only maintain one version of the bootstrap script. Fabric 2.0 depends on those images and they are tagged properly. Versions less than 2.0 you will see those two errors, but you can completely ignore it.

Comment: you mean that these both files are not needed for the proper work of fabric 1.4.2? 

I can completely ignore: baseos and nodeenv?

If not? Which version should I take to receive its full support for 1.4.2? What is or was the main purpose of this images? If they are not needed anymore.

I want to receive a complete LTS version 1.4.2 for research purpose and am unsure what to do with this incomplete version next.

Comment: You don't need baseos or nodeenv for v1.4.2. They will be used by the future v2.0.0. You can ignore the errors on v1.4.2 download. Actually v1.4.3 was released August 26th and is the recommended release.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `docker images` command you should see that the IMAGE ID for "latest" and "1.4.2" are the same - they are just different tags for the same image.

Don't worry too much about "pulling" images - when Docker needs to create/run a Container based on an Image it will pull the image if it can't be found locally.

I think you are right that there is a bug in the script regarding versions 1.4.2/2.0